# Display foriegnkey fields in Django template for a CreateView

Tags: django, python-3.x, foreign-keys, django-class-based-views

I am trying to display a checklist in the CreateView using the values in the  ForeignKey fields for descriptions.

models.py

```
class Structure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    description =models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SelectedFramework(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    structure = models.ForegignKey(Structure)
    selected = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

views.py

```
class FrameworkCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = SelectedFramework
    fields =['structure', 'selected']
    template_name = 'catalogue/structure.html'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(FrameworkCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

structure.html

```
{% extends 'catalogue\base.html' %}
{% block container %}
<h2>{% block title %}Structures{% endblock title %}</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="col-sm-10">{{form.structure}} {{form.selected}}</div><br>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The code above works but will display the ForeignKey 'structure' as a dropdown list with the values of `__str__`. Is there a way to display string for `structure.name` and `structure.description` with the checkbox from `selected` in the CreateView?

Answer (score 0):

In your template use:

```
{{ form.structure.name }}
{{ form.structure.description}}
```

Comment: I already tried both that and using the double underscore to reference the foreignkey but all it did was made the field all blank

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom form, override the save method and create `Structure` object manually there:

```
class FrameworkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    structure_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    structure_description = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SelectedFramework
        fields = [
            'structure_name', 'structure_description', 'selected'
        ]

    def save(self, commit=False):
        instance = super(FrameworkForm, self).save(commit=False)
        structure = Structure(
            name=self.cleaned_data.get('structure_name'),
            description=self.cleaned_data.get('structure_description')
        )
        structure.save()
        instance.structure = structure
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Also add `form_class = FrameworkForm` to your view instead of `fields = ['structure', 'selected']`

**EDIT:**

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
<ul>
{% for structure in form.fields.structure.choices.queryset %}
    <li>{{ structure.name }} - {{ structure.description }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: that just generates two charfields. I am trying to display the foreign key values

Comment: Also Django does not allow the use of both `form_class` and `fields` for the `CreateView` you can use one or the other but not both

Comment: I know Django does not allow both, I wrote that you add `form_class` instead of `fields`. I edited my answer, it might work for you.

Comment: didn't work everything inside that for loop was blank not sure why. I tried replacing the dots with underscores and still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get fields by iterating in the template. You have to use-

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

don't have to use any dot notation to get the field. If you want to get the label of the field you can use `{{ field.label}}` usually before `{{field}}`

Comment: @Baishakhi_Dasgupta that will just give me a dropdown with one check box instead of a list with multiple check boxes